# Stata Panel: How to assign value to a group, merge?

Tags: stata

I have a panel of firms (id, year). Each firm also belongs to a specific country. Now I would like to add a GDP time series by country.

The goal is that e.g. each firm from the US is assigned the US' GDP of that year, etc.

Can anyone tell me how to go about that? Is there some way to use the `merge` command here?

Comment: Could you post your first attempts with `merge`, using the three unique identifiers (`country`, `id`, year`), to see if that works fine? Try `merge` in `1:m` mode.

Comment: the problem is that the gdp time series does not have the id identifier, just country and year. that is why stata gives me an error when i use merge 1:m.

Comment: Alright. What about `m:m` with just country and year? Given that all firms from the same year and country are going to receive the same GDP figure, that information should be sufficient.

Comment: You don't need the `id` there, just `country` and `year` -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help file for [`merge`](http://stata.com/help.cgi?merge) rightfully states, `merge m:m` is a wrong approach most of the time. If you have the firm data set as

```
clear
input country id year profit
1 1 2010 152
1 1 2011 -8
1 2 2010 1090
2 3 2010 502
2 3 2011 -15
end
tempfile firms
save `firms'
```

and the country file

```
clear
input country year gdp
1 2010 287582354
1 2011 298723412
2 2010 89734531
2 2011 87340120
end
tempfile gdp
save `gdp'
```

then starting from your `firms` file, you can merge the results as follows:

```
use `firms', clear
merge m:1 country year using `gdp'
* check results
tab _merge
assert _merge == 3
* clean up the remaining mess
drop if _merge !=3
drop _merge
```

This should produce the output that looks like

```
Result                           # of obs.
-----------------------------------------
not matched                             0
matched                                 5  (_merge==3)
-----------------------------------------
```

and if you don't have anything that was not matched (which is my verification and clean up code looks at), you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works perfectly! i had a hunch that m:m was not the way to go but just needed a great example like yours to understand the merge command.